# How to set/stick a date in the datepicker using classic ASP after a form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp-classic, datepicker

As my title explains, I am trying to stick or set the date of date-picker once the form is submitted by clicking "Search" button. I tried to do it as following under script section but it doesn't work. Neither it gives any error nor the date sticks once the search button is clicked and form is submitted. I researched it but couldn't find solution for it. Any help is much appreciated.

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();            
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text][id*=startDate]').datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/Images/cal.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {    $('#HiddenField1').val(dateText) },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1

        });
        var theDate;

        if ($('#HiddenField1').val() != "" && $('#HiddenField1').val() != null) {
            theDate = $('#HiddenField1').val();
        }
        else {
            theDate = new Date();
        }
        console.log (theDate);
       // alert(theDate);
        $('input[type=text][id*=startDate]').datepicker("option", "showAnim", 'bounce');
        $('input[type=text][id*=startDate]').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yy');
        $('input[type=text][id*=startDate]').datepicker("option", "altFormat", 'mm/dd/yy');
        $('input[type=text][id*=startDate]').datepicker('setDate', theDate);    
});
</script>
<div id="data">
    <table>
        <form method=get action="<%=request("script_name")%>">
            <tr>
                <td><b><font>Start Date: </td>
                <td><input class="datepicker" id= "startDate" name="startDate" type="text"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" id= "HiddenField1" name="HiddenField1" type="text"></td> 
                <td><b><font>End Date: </td>
                <td><input class="datepicker" id= "endDate" name="endDate" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style= "padding:10px;" colspan=4 align=center>
                    <input type=hidden name=action value=OrderDate>
                    <input type=submit value=Search>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What's in `request("script_name")`? Because that's where you're sending the form data. Are you ending up back at this same asp page after submitting? If so, how?

Comment: @Martha They are just calling the [`Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms525396(v=vs.90).aspx) value which returns the current script name so in effect it's POSTing to itself. The reason `Request("script_name")` works is because how [collections on objects are handled in ASP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms525228(v=vs.90).aspx). Wouldn't recommend it though to easy to have `script_name` in multiple collections like `.Form`, `.QueryString` and `.Cookies` for example.

Comment: @Martha : Yes its ending up back in the same page after submitting. I had updated my code.

Comment: @Lankymart: ah, `ServerVariables` was the possibility I wasn't even considering, because I would never ever trust an unqualified `request()` to guess that I meant servervariables. Well, actually, I never use unqualified `request()`, period -- I always explicitly use `Request.Form()` or `Request.Querystring()` or, rarely, `Request.ServerVariables()` -- but that's because I want to know what my code is doing, silly me.

Comment: @Lankymart Can you please help me out? I tried to do it using hidden fields but it set the today's date not current selected date from the date picker. I know it's because its going to "else" statement and taking new Date();

Comment: Once you POST back to the page the values in the `HiddenField1` will be gone unless you set them back using the values POSTed from the `<form>`, i.e. `<input type="hidden" id= "HiddenField1" name="HiddenField1" type="text" value="<%= Request.Form("startDate")  %>">`. But then why do you need a hidden field can you not specify `value = "<%= Request.Form("startDate") %>"` on the `<input>` for the datepicker?

Comment: @Lankymart: I tried doing value = "<%= Request.Form("startDate") %>" on the <input> for the datepicker before I decided to do hidden file thing but it didn't work. I just realized I just need to do "Request("startDate") %>". It works! Thank you so so much

Comment: Sorry, missed you are posting using GET not POST. Accessing variables from GET form posts uses `Request.QueryString(...)` instead of `Request.Form(...)`.